# How to get Korean language characters to display on a website?

Tags: html, localization

We have a website that will be displayed in various languages. Our footer gives the option to view the Korean site.

```
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.aspx">English</a></li>
      <li><a href="de/index.aspx">Deutsch</a></li>
      <li><a href="nl/index.aspx">Nederlands</a></li>
      <li><a href="kr/index.aspx">한국의</a></li>
    </ul>
```

As I developed this locally, everything showed up well. 
[image: Korean characters during development]

But when I launched it to our testing server which is in a .net environment, it did not display well.
[image: Korean Characters when deployed to testing server]

When I did a search for finding solutions I found a site which covered some basics about displaying Korean http://www.katpatuka.org/pub/doc/content-language/ko.htm

They suggested adding the following `<meta>` tags

```
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=KS_C_5601">
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-language" CONTENT="ko">
```

Which I tried but to no avail. What can resolve this?

Comment: What about `charset=UTF-8`?

Comment: @ExplosionPills just tried it, but did still did not display. Thanks though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: Displaying Korean Text in a Webpage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107249/php-displaying-korean-text-in-a-webpage)

Comment: @NathanSakoetoe NO, that link you mention was in PHP. I specifically mentioned that my site is hosted in a .net environment. So please remove your vote to close.

Answer (score 2):

The [sample page](http://www.katpatuka.org/pub/doc/content-language/ko.htm) mentioned is sent by the server with the HTTP header

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-9
```

This must be all wrong. ISO-8859-9 is an 8-bit code, known as Latin/Turkish or ISO Latin5.

A `meta` tag cannot override the encoding information in HTTP headers. You need to fix the server configuration.

The page seems to display OK if I manually (using browser settings, overriding HTTP headers) set the encoding to “Korean” in Chrome, whatever that might mean (windows-949, perhaps). Ditto on IE 10. In Firefox, there are three Korean encodings selectable. The one that makes the page display OK is “EUC-KR”. The differences between it and windows-949 might (or might not) be insignificant here.

So it’s rather confusing. I would really suggest converting the encoding to UTF-8 and declaring it in HTTP headers. (Actually, it suffices to use “UTF-8 with BOM”, since browsers will infer UTF-8 from the BOM, overriding any other information.)

Answer (score 1):

How about trying this?

```
<html lang="ko">
```