# Language accents displaying as ??? on my website

Tags: html

Currently I am trying to display *[Korean Language](https://www.google.com/search?q=Korean%20Language&oq=Korean%20Language&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l2.1712j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)* characters on my website but instead it's displaying text which looks like ??? where the **Korean language** should be.

You can seen an example in the screen shot below.

[image]

I have tried to add the following to my `meta` and no luck.

```
<meta http-equiv="content-language" content="ko"/>
<html lang="ko" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

Here's the current structure of my head content.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ko" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
<meta charset="UTF-8" >
<!-- <meta http-equiv="content-language" content="ko"/> === commented out as it didn't do anything.--> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
<meta property="og:image" content="" />
<meta property="og:url" content="" />
<meta property="og:title" content="" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta name="keywords" content="" />
<meta name="description" content="" />
</head>
```

**EDIT:** I have viewed some of the following questions and they did **NOT** help solve my issue. [Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16945681/how-to-get-korean-language-characters-to-display-on-a-website) & [Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107249/php-displaying-korean-text-in-a-webpage).

Comment: Are you using XHTML, as `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml` suggests, or HTML5? Does it work in any other browser?

Comment: @AndrewMorton I am using HTML5. Added that in for testing as I saw an answer on here recommended it, appears the issue exists on all browsers even if I remove the `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml` portion.

Comment: Where are you getting data from? Maybe a database?

Comment: Can you make a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue? Of if that doesn't work, please provide a link to your website, so we can test.

Comment: What is the _encoding_ of your page?

Answer (score 0):

The meta tag

```
<meta http-equiv="content-language" content="ko"/>
```

is not declaring the encoding of the text. It is only a clue to search engines that your page is in the language specified. The lang attribute has the same effect.

You should use the charset attribute:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```